# Microsoft Word - How to add a button to insert file

Tags: vba, button, ms-word

I want to add a button in microsoft word that when I click it opens microsoft explorer to insert a file in the word page.

I already have the button but dont know what action should i do to implement that.

[image]

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by "insert a file?" Are you inserting text from another Word file? Inserting a picture or PDF? See also the section on working with files and directories on the MVP webpage: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA.htm.

Answer (score 0):

You could, instead of adding a Button in your document, add the Insert File command to the QAT for that document.

This is a bit more subtle but **works in non-macro enabled documents**. In my opinion it is much easier to do.

[image]

You would want to draw your user's attention to it. Many places will not allow macros to run. It may run on Macs, which will not work with your ActiveX button. Here is my webpage on [Modifying the QAT](http://addbalance.com/word/QATmodification.htm).